# How does stackoverflow check the attention of reviewer?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review

I was just reviewing on Late answer post over stackoverflow, and after moment when I cleared my review, it says following :
[image]

I was amazed by seeing this message... :) indeed I was paying attention, but my question is what tech or algorithm it follows to check whether reviewers really paying his attention or not ?
(My guess is detecting time spending on the question with scroll and mouse moment, but not sure..)

Comment: Nothing so magic; just knowing in advance what action is right for a fake audit review.

Comment: As Martjin points out, there isn't much here as far as algorithms go . although in the future there is potential elsewhere, using AI -type algorithms

Comment: @Adel There actually is a fair bit.  Deciding on which posts to use as a clearly good/bad example of something isn't bulletproof; the algorithms have been shown to be off often enough.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ohh really !! ... it was a test as it is already mentioned.. but any way I thought there would be some nice way.. some logic etc :).. thanks Martijn

Comment: @Servy - Hmm, that's interesting. So sometimes the algorithms  mess up . Thank you!!

Comment: You are welcome; and kudos for paying attention! We like reviewers who carefully review posts!